# Invalid processed submission: expecting value for field 'field_name' to be of type string, null given

Tags: php, laravel-5, dms

I have a ObjectValue type class as Test

```
const FIELD_NAME = 'fieldName';

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $fieldName;
public function __construct($fieldName)
{
    $this->fieldName = $fieldName;
    parent::__construct();

}
protected function define(ClassDefinition $class)
{
    $class->property($this->fieldName)->asString();
}
```

and corresponding Mapper class

```
class TestMapper extends IndependentValueObjectMapper
```

{

```
protected function define(MapperDefinition $map)
{
    $map->type(Test::class);

    $map->property(Test::FIELD_NAME)->to('field_name')->asVarchar(255);
}
```

}

Migrated same to dms. When I try to add the `field_name` and save, it gives an error as follows

> Invalid processed submission: expecting value for field 'field_name' to be of type string, null given (View: \dms-org\web.laravel\resources\views\components\form\staged-form.blade.php)

I'm not giving null, Its an string that I'm adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are playing around Entities with constructor !

Could you please put the parent constructor call on first line

```
public function __construct($fieldName)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->fieldName = $fieldName;

}
```

This will ensure that if you call any value on your constructor, the parent class has already been set up correctly.

I am not sure in your case ...

Ignore me if i am wrong

Thanks / Good luck!! :)

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me !!  When I call `parent::__construct();` at first line. It is solving the error. I'm new to this framework, so not aware of it.  Anyway Thanks.